# why can not scrapgoogle map rank items more then 6 using selenium python

Tags: python, google-apps-script, pagination, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get some value from google map ranking. I want get value from google map top ranking 1 to 20 but I am getting only top 6 ranks only. maybe it can not scroll down the next page. Anyone can help me.
in the scraper code `num_places` is 20

my scraper code is:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from drivers.driver import get_driver

PRICE_LEVEL_LABELS = {
    '安価': 1,
    'お手頃': 2,
    '高級': 3,
    '贅沢': 4,
    '$': 1,
    '$$': 2,
    '$$$': 3,
    '$$$$': 4,
}


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, key_words, latitude, longitude, num_places):
        self.key_words = key_words
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.num_places = num_places
        self.driver = get_driver()


    def scrape_places(self):
        search_url = f"https://www.google.co.jp/maps/search/{self.key_words}/@{self.latitude},{self.longitude},15z"
        self.driver.get(search_url)
        sleep(5)

        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        search_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))
        search_box.send_keys(self.key_words + Keys.RETURN)

        places = []
        SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
        last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        links = []

        while len(links) < self.num_places:
            place_links = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href, "/maps/place/")]')
            new_links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in place_links]
            
            
            for link in new_links:
                if link not in links:
                    links.append(link)
            print(f"Collected {len(links)} links so far.")

            if len(links) >= self.num_places:
                
                break
           
               

            #Scroll down
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

            new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break

            last_height = new_height
        
        for link in links:
            self.driver.get(link)
            place_data = self._scrape_place_data()
            places.append(place_data)

        self.driver.quit()
        return places
                
        

    def _scrape_place_data(self):
        data = {}
        sleep(5)

        try:
            name_element = self.driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//h1[@class="DUwDvf fontHeadlineLarge"]')
            data['name'] = name_element.text
            print(f"Name found: {data['name']}")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Name not found")
                    

        try:
            address_element = self.driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "Io6YTe") and contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium") and contains(@class, "kR99db")]')

            if address_element.text != '':
                data['address'] = address_element.text
            else:
                data['address'] = None
            print(f"Address found: {data['address']}")

        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Address not found")
            pass

        try:
            url_element = self.driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//a[@class="CsEnBe"]')
            if url_element.get_attribute('href').startswith('https://business.google.com'):
                print('Invalid URL found')
                data['url'] = None
            else:
                data['url'] = url_element.get_attribute('href')
                print(f"url found: {data['url']}")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('URL not found')
            data['url'] = None
            pass
                
            
        try:
            rating_element = self.driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"F7nice")]/span/span[@aria-hidden="true"]')
            if rating_element.text != '':
                data['rating'] = float(rating_element.text)
            else:
                data['rating'] = None
            print(f"rating found: {data['rating']}")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Rating not found')
            pass

        try:
            rating_total_element = self.driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"F7nice")]/span[2]/span/span[@aria-label]')
            
            if rating_total_element.text != '':
                # extract only the numbers from the string
                data['rating_total'] = int(
                    ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, rating_total_element.text)))
            else:
                data['rating_total'] = None
            print(f"total rating found: {data['rating_total']}")

        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        sleep(3)
        return data
```

Chrome drivers is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

DRIVER_PATH = ChromeDriverManager(path='drivers').install()


def get_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
    print('driver is:', driver.title)
    return driver
```